# How to convert Postman OAuth 2.0 to Python

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, postman

I have been getting the issue when I'm trying to convert Postman OAuth 2.0 to Python3.  I tried to research but seems unfortunate for me, I did not find any example
Here is my code:

```
from rauth import OAuth2Service
import json

def get_token(client_id, client_secret):
    access_token = None

    service = OAuth2Service(
        name="Viafoura",
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        access_token_url='https://auth.viafoura.io/authorize_client'
    )

    data = {
            'scope': 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx',
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        }

    session = service.get_auth_session(data=data)

    access_token = session
```

Here is OAuth 2.0 on Postman and it's working:

[image]

I want to get the access_token via Python3. Could anyone please help me on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it can help you, an example with the basic algorithm of OAuth2

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from requests import post, auth, exceptions
from json import loads

if __name__ == '__main__':

    client_id = ''
    client_secret = ''
    user = ''
    password = ''

    access_point = 'https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token'
    grant_type = 'password'

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    auth = auth.HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)

    data = {'grant_type': grant_type,
            'username': user,
            'password': password}

    resp = None
    try:
        resp = post(access_point, auth=auth, data=data, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    except exceptions.ConnectionError:
        exit(1)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        resp = loads(resp.text)
        if 'access_token' in resp:
            print(resp['access_token'])
            exit(0)

    exit(1)
```

You need to fix access point, grant type. This source code can be found [here](https://github.com/caa06d9c/Examples/blob/master/Python/tools/oauth2/get_access_token/run.py)

Sorry, I can't help directly with Viafoura and OAuth2Service library.